# How does a DELETE FROM with a SELECT in the WHERE work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking at an application and I found this SQL:

```
DELETE FROM Phrase 
WHERE Modified < (SELECT Modified FROM PhraseSource WHERE Id = Phrase.PhraseId)
```

The intention of the SQL is to delete rows from Phrase where there are more recent rows in the PhraseSource table.

Now I know the tables Phrase and PhraseSource have the same columns and Modified holds the number of seconds since 1970 but I cannot understand how/why this works or what it is doing. When I look at it then it seems like on the left of the < it is just one column and on the right side of the > it would be many rows. Does it even make any sense?

The two tables are identical and have the following structure

```
Id - GUID primary key
... 
... 
...
Modified int
```

the `...` columns are about ten columns containing text and numeric data. The `PhraseSource` table may or may not contain more recent rows with a higher number in the Modified column and different text and numeric data.

Comment: It's a subquery that (I think?) will run for each value of `PhraseId` in `Phrase`. Since it's (presumably) a single value (scalar) returned, it can then do a simple comparison. This seems like a suboptimal approach (and I honestly can't quite figure out how it's intended to function), but it's hard to say without seeing the data structure.

Comment: The data structure is very simple.  Just two tables with a primary key of Id a few columns and the modified column with a count of seconds since 1970.  For me it seems confusing but maybe thats just me :-)

Comment: Saying it's simple doesn't really provide details. Can you provide some sample tables with a few rows to clarify, as well as expected result after the query and actual result after query? Without more, it's hard to say what the best approach would be.

Comment: @CollinD - I updated the question a bit to provide more details.  PhraseSource would typically contain perhaps 5050 rows and Phrase 5000 rows.  There may be 50 new rows added and perhaps 50 rows that are more recent in PhraseSource. I'm trying to get hold of the DDL now but didn't add it as I don't have access on this computer as I am connected remotely.

Comment: The DDL isn't really necessary. Are `PhraseSource` and `Phrase` identical tables? I'd go with something closer to Martin's answer, that will be much more efficient.

Comment: Yes they are identical.  Both have primary key of Id.  Thanks

Comment: I think you're set then unless you can provide a few sample rows like i said before. Not enough info to improve from below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `SELECT` statement in parenthesis is a sub-query or nested query.

What happens is that for each row, the `Modified` column value is compared with the result of the sub-query (which is run once for each of the rows in the Phrase table).

The sub-query has a `WHERE` statement, so it finds a row that has the same `ID` as the row from `Phrase` table that we are currently evaluating and returns the `Modified` value (which is for a sigle row, actually a single scalar value).

The two `Modified` values are compared and in case the `Phrase`'s row has been modified before the row in `PhraseSource`, it is deleted.

As you can see this approach is **not efficient**, because it requires the database to run a **separate query for each of the rows** in the `Phrase` table  (although I imagine that some databases might be smart enough to optimize this a little bit).

### A better solution

The more efficient solution would be to use `INNER JOIN`:

```
DELETE p FROM Phrase p
INNER JOIN PhraseSource ps
  ON p.PhraseId=ps.Id 
WHERE p.Modified < ps.Modified
```

This should do the exact same thing as your query, but using efficient `JOIN` mechanism. `INNER JOIN` uses the `ON` statement to choose how to "match" rows in two different tables (which is done very efficiently by the DB) and then again compares the `Modified` values of matching rows.

Comment: Id is the primary key here.  Based on what you said then I get this idea it might not be a very good way to do this. Am I correct with thinking that?

Comment: I have updated my answer with what I think could be more efficient solution :-)

Comment: Thanks Martin,  I'll suggest that your change is made to the code. I have another similar question so will post that also.  Would appreciate if you can have a look at that one.